# How to forward constructor arguments to boost::optional

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-optional

I have the following simple struct:

```
struct X
{
    X(std::string name, int value): name_(name), value_(value){}

    std::string name_;
    int value_;
};
```

I would like to use it with boost optional without copying. Here is one option:

```
boost::optional<X> op;
op.emplace("abc", 5);
```

Is it possible without using emplace function ? (I mean one line expression)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, just construct it with the "in place" tag which forwards ctor args!

```
boost::optional<X> op(boost::optional::in_place_init, "abc", 5);
```

([ref](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/reference/header__boost_optional_optional_hpp_/detailed_semantics___optional_values.html#reference_optional_in_place_init))

FWIW if you don't mind a move then this works too:

```
boost::optional<X> op(X("abc", 5));
```

Scan down that reference page; there are loads of ways to construct or fill a `boost::optional`.

Comment: Your nose is a reference page

Comment: boost::optional<X> op(X("abc", 5)); uses a copy constructor

Comment: @Irbis Why's that? There is a `optional<T>::optional( T&& v )` ctor with documented move semantics (see linked ref), and the argument here is a temporary (and consequently an rvalue).

Comment: You're right. I have defined a copy ctor to see if it is called and move constructor has not been generated. When I define copy and move ctors I see that move ctor is called.